# Why promise resolved before event?

Tags: javascript

```js
const first = document.getElementById('first');
const second = document.getElementById('second');

first.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('fist click start');
  wait(10000);
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('resolve promise');
  }).then((data) => console.log('Promise resolved', data));
  console.log('fist click finish');
});
second.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('second click start');
  console.log('second click finish');
});


// simulate a long running process
function wait(ms) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = start;
  while (end < start + ms) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="first">first</button>
<button id="second">second</button>
```

First we click first button
And immediately after that - second button

we can see this:

```
fist click start
fist click finish
Promise resolved resolve promise
second click start
second click finish
```

I expected the promise callback to be called last - but it's called before second button click callback.
i.e. the event queue should look like this(at the time of second button clicked):

```
first button click
second button click
promise
```

Please help me clarify this moment.

Comment: _I expected the promise callback to be called last_ Whats the rational behind such thought?

Comment: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Comment: In which order are you clicking the buttons? If you did click them at the same time, it might be reasonable to expect that the promise callback is delayed after both of them - but clicking at the same time is not possible.

Comment: Thank you - I clarified that moment - first click first button, then second. Immediately.

Comment: @ArslArsl Well "immediately" is not quick enough, by the time you clicked the second button the promise already was resolved and did schedule the callback…

Comment: @Bergi ok - if I put promise after wait function? - it still outputs the same

Comment: Well blocking to wait should never be done - and the promise is still resolved before the second event has a chance to execute its callback, as it is blocked as well.

Comment: Ok. Now I see. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing nothing but resolving the promise inside it's definition. That's normal to act it like this. If you put a timeout to resolve the promise, you'll see that then is executed after that timeout. Check this example:

The key is, when you resolve the promise is important to when to run the `.then` block.

```js
const first = document.getElementById('first');
const second = document.getElementById('second');

first.addEventListener('click', (e) =>  {
    console.log('first click start');
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("promise started");
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve('resolve promise');
        }, 3000);
    }).then((data) => console.log('Promise resolved', data))

    console.log('fist click finish');
});
second.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log('second click start');
    console.log('second click finish');
});
```

```html
<div id='first'>Click me first!</div>
<div id='second'>Click me second!</div>
```

Comment: Ok I see it, and understand your point. But here - what I don't get - why Promise resolve is put before second button event in the callback.

Comment: Think them as seperate events. If you click the second button before the promise resolves, it will run first. then the promise next step is executed. Think promises as waiting to complete something and running others after that, like an event chain.

Comment: Ok. Suppose promise goes like a separate event - but it should be it still should be after second button click - in the event queue

Comment: Button clicks are not queued, they are triggered by user input.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a promise is that it's usually async. You call it, and continue with your code, and once it's finished, it will trigger the code in your `then`.

Now in your case, you're not doing anything that takes time with your promise, so it's instantly getting resolved. If you had called an API and it would take 2 seconds to resolve, it would go last.

So the order of events here is:

1. Clicked first
2. Trigger first console log
3. Create promise
4. Continue code - trigger second console log
5. Promise finishes because there's nothing to do, console logs
6. ... move to second click